# operator norm a linear transformation

Tags: operator-theory, linear-transformations

> > Define $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ by
> >     $$ Ax=(x_1-x_2, x_1+x_2,x_1) $$
> >     Show that $\|A\|=\sqrt{2}.$

My attempt:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then

$$\|Ax\|^2=(x_1-x_2)^2 + (x_1+x_2)^2+ {x_1}^2 = 2(x_1^2+x_2^2)+{x_1}^2=2\|x\|^2+ {x_1}^2.$$
Thus, 
$$\|Ax\|= \sqrt{2\|x\|^2+ {x_1}^2}. $$
Note that
$$ \|a\|= \sup \Big\{ \dfrac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} : x\in \mathbb{R}^2, x \neq0 \Big\} $$
$$ = \sup \Big\{ \sqrt{2 + \dfrac{{x_1}^2}{\|x\|^2}} : x\in \mathbb{R}^2, x \neq0 \Big\}$$

I'm stucked here. i know that $x_1^2<\|x\|^2$. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show that $\|A\|=\sqrt2$ because it isn't. Note that:

- $\bigl\|(1,0)\bigr\|=1$;
- $\bigl\|A(1,0)\bigr\|=\bigl\|(1,1,1)\bigr\|=\sqrt3$.

Therefore, $\|A\|\geqslant\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed by Jose, $\|A\| \neq \sqrt{2}$.

The problem that you want to solve is

$$\max_{x} 3x_1^2 + 2x_2^2$$

subject to $$x_1^2+x_2^2 =1 $$

which can be reduced to

$$\max_{x} 3x_1^2 + 2(1-x_1^2)=x_1^2+2$$

subject to $$0 \leq x_1^2 \leq 1 $$

Hence $\|A\|= \sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\|Ax\|^2=(x_1-x_2)^2 + (x_1+x_2)^2+ {x_1}^2 = 2(x_1^2+x_2^2)+x_1^2=2\|x\|^2+ x_1^2 \le 3\|x\|^2$$

Thus, $\|A\| \le \sqrt{3}$.

On the other hand,

$$\|A\| \ge \frac{\|A(1,0)\|}{\|(1,0)\|} = \|(1,1,1)\| = \sqrt{3}$$

Thus, $\|A\| = \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: $(x_1+x_2)^2 \ne ||x||^2$  !!!!

Comment: @Fred Thanks, corrected.